# How to set position of select text in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I have a plot I create from a script provided by a webtool called REVIGO. It gives plots of biological terms and how they overlap with each other, however the text is overlapping in some parts so they are not readable. Is there a way to change the positioning of text in ggplot for some cases, and not move the plot the text is associated with?

For example, my plot looks like:

[image]

The text in a couple places is overlapping and I want to move the text to be readable without moving the circles themselves.

The code I used to make this plot (which also provides the input data) is:

```
library( ggplot2 );
library( scales );

revigo.names <- c("term_ID","description","frequency_%","plot_X","plot_Y","plot_size","log10_p_value","uniqueness","dispensability");
revigo.data <- rbind(c("GO:0002376","immune system process",16.463,-0.302,-3.807, 3.455,-8.3307,0.995,0.000),
c("GO:0006928","movement of cell or subcellular component",10.987, 1.052, 1.113, 3.280,-8.8153,0.965,0.000),
c("GO:0007610","behavior", 3.254,-1.620, 0.960, 2.752,-4.0048,0.994,0.000),
c("GO:0008150","biological_process",100.000,-6.029,-0.499, 4.239,-8.7447,1.000,0.000),
c("GO:0009987","cellular process",90.329,-5.288, 0.130, 4.195,-10.0701,0.999,0.000),
c("GO:0010243","response to organonitrogen compound", 4.697, 6.870,-2.756, 2.911,-12.7100,0.865,0.000),
c("GO:0023052","signaling",36.613, 2.976,-6.718, 3.803,-7.1931,0.996,0.000),
c("GO:0032501","multicellular organismal process",41.143, 3.761,-0.715, 3.853,-17.2741,0.997,0.000),
c("GO:0032502","developmental process",33.982,-2.865,-0.660, 3.770,-14.4202,0.996,0.000),
c("GO:0034762","regulation of transmembrane transport", 2.452,-3.982, 3.261, 2.629,-13.4123,0.788,0.000),
c("GO:0040007","growth", 5.447, 0.651,-0.889, 2.975,-4.2140,0.995,0.000),
c("GO:0040011","locomotion", 9.452, 2.305,-0.865, 3.215,-8.1068,0.995,0.000),
c("GO:0050896","response to stimulus",49.302, 3.556,-5.122, 3.932,-17.7852,0.997,0.000),
c("GO:0051179","localization",36.018,-0.564,-0.041, 3.795,-8.9245,0.996,0.000),
c("GO:0051704","multi-organism process", 9.873, 1.677,-5.787, 3.234,-4.6925,0.995,0.000),
c("GO:0065007","biological regulation",67.069,-4.157, 0.147, 4.065,-15.5918,0.998,0.000),
c("GO:0007154","cell communication",36.705,-0.841,-2.282, 3.804,-8.3595,0.992,0.006),
c("GO:0008283","cell proliferation",11.321, 2.644, 1.154, 3.293,-4.5376,0.982,0.024),
c("GO:0042391","regulation of membrane potential", 2.204,-0.568,-6.816, 2.583,-10.6073,0.895,0.035),
c("GO:0043086","negative regulation of catalytic activity", 4.934, 4.164,-2.157, 2.932,-4.9172,0.880,0.039),
c("GO:0019216","regulation of lipid metabolic process", 1.685, 3.142, 6.777, 2.467,-6.3215,0.880,0.043),
c("GO:0044057","regulation of system process", 2.862,-6.608, 1.584, 2.696,-13.1469,0.868,0.046),
c("GO:0051093","negative regulation of developmental process", 4.720,-4.950,-3.614, 2.913,-9.9031,0.830,0.050),
c("GO:0006793","phosphorus metabolic process",18.702,-4.363, 6.140, 3.511,-6.8729,0.961,0.053),
c("GO:0008284","positive regulation of cell proliferation", 4.859,-0.261, 4.128, 2.926,-9.2882,0.832,0.055),
c("GO:0065008","regulation of biological quality",20.202,-0.644, 5.306, 3.544,-20.3125,0.920,0.057),
c("GO:0050865","regulation of cell activation", 3.174, 2.497,-4.613, 2.741,-4.7878,0.917,0.062),
c("GO:0065009","regulation of molecular function",17.288,-1.972, 4.374, 3.477,-17.1959,0.923,0.078),
c("GO:0048518","positive regulation of biological process",30.969, 0.597, 8.033, 3.730,-15.2993,0.895,0.095),
c("GO:0051128","regulation of cellular component organization",13.335, 1.445, 4.799, 3.364,-4.5003,0.899,0.104),
c("GO:0007169","transmembrane receptor protein tyrosine kinase signaling pathway", 3.976, 6.886, 4.332, 2.839,-7.5986,0.845,0.114),
c("GO:0032101","regulation of response to external stimulus", 3.976, 6.545, 2.631, 2.839,-9.0405,0.838,0.114),
c("GO:0048519","negative regulation of biological process",26.855,-0.542, 7.989, 3.668,-12.9469,0.898,0.134),
c("GO:0044238","primary metabolic process",60.306,-3.339, 6.565, 4.019,-4.5229,0.961,0.140),
c("GO:0042221","response to chemical",23.993, 7.702,-0.115, 3.619,-24.7399,0.923,0.160),
c("GO:0009628","response to abiotic stimulus", 6.705, 8.008, 1.525, 3.066,-11.1726,0.938,0.174),
c("GO:0007187","G-protein coupled receptor signaling pathway, coupled to cyclic nucleotide second messenger", 1.033, 5.463, 5.279, 2.255,-5.0942,0.874,0.186),
c("GO:0031099","regeneration", 1.016,-3.828,-4.295, 2.248,-4.6216,0.955,0.186),
c("GO:0009719","response to endogenous stimulus", 9.175, 6.984, 0.467, 3.202,-15.8069,0.935,0.188),
c("GO:0098657","import into cell", 0.415,-3.347, 2.843, 1.863,-4.7077,0.928,0.190),
c("GO:0051239","regulation of multicellular organismal process",15.268,-6.085, 3.408, 3.423,-18.1433,0.885,0.192),
c("GO:0007268","chemical synaptic transmission", 3.474, 5.008, 6.277, 2.780,-4.7471,0.914,0.194),
c("GO:0050794","regulation of cellular process",60.427, 0.909, 7.170, 4.020,-15.1986,0.875,0.198),
c("GO:0009605","response to external stimulus",12.043, 7.990, 0.686, 3.320,-7.7520,0.932,0.202),
c("GO:0019222","regulation of metabolic process",35.730,-0.798, 6.924, 3.792,-8.7399,0.888,0.217),
c("GO:0048589","developmental growth", 3.272,-5.765,-3.288, 2.754,-4.6289,0.942,0.220),
c("GO:0048729","tissue morphogenesis", 3.572,-4.454,-4.112, 2.792,-4.2055,0.942,0.223),
c("GO:0048732","gland development", 2.418,-5.936,-2.151, 2.623,-3.9830,0.930,0.224),
c("GO:0032879","regulation of localization",14.409,-3.921, 4.876, 3.398,-19.9830,0.839,0.231),
c("GO:0006950","response to stress",21.310, 7.271,-0.252, 3.567,-11.7905,0.925,0.241),
c("GO:0048583","regulation of response to stimulus",21.610, 7.157, 2.071, 3.574,-14.0640,0.849,0.242),
c("GO:0031323","regulation of cellular metabolic process",33.837, 1.983, 7.193, 3.768,-7.3665,0.804,0.256),
c("GO:0003008","system process",11.575,-6.863, 1.039, 3.303,-14.5229,0.965,0.259),
c("GO:0050789","regulation of biological process",63.456, 0.625, 7.037, 4.041,-16.1244,0.896,0.274),
c("GO:0051899","membrane depolarization", 0.565,-1.372,-6.528, 1.996,-4.2411,0.910,0.284),
c("GO:0061024","membrane organization", 7.299,-5.167, 4.037, 3.102,-4.4237,0.987,0.286),
c("GO:0035150","regulation of tube size", 0.675,-0.489,-6.505, 2.072,-5.1129,0.901,0.290),
c("GO:0009636","response to toxic substance", 1.264, 6.039,-4.714, 2.342,-5.3072,0.915,0.292),
c("GO:0061041","regulation of wound healing", 0.750, 5.568, 3.354, 2.117,-5.7696,0.869,0.296),
c("GO:0007165","signal transduction",33.618, 5.808, 3.554, 3.765,-20.2403,0.784,0.296),
c("GO:0010038","response to metal ion", 1.829, 6.463,-4.185, 2.502,-5.0768,0.911,0.307),
c("GO:0001101","response to acid chemical", 1.858, 6.221,-3.913, 2.509,-5.3072,0.911,0.308),
c("GO:0043066","negative regulation of apoptotic process", 4.749,-4.234,-2.719, 2.916,-5.6778,0.845,0.315),
c("GO:0042493","response to drug", 2.366, 6.792,-3.628, 2.614,-12.6716,0.908,0.319),
c("GO:0010035","response to inorganic substance", 2.816, 6.714,-3.232, 2.689,-6.8125,0.906,0.327),
c("GO:0048856","anatomical structure development",31.558,-4.976,-4.080, 3.738,-12.4157,0.940,0.339),
c("GO:0051716","cellular response to stimulus",40.358, 7.607, 0.187, 3.845,-21.1158,0.911,0.359),
c("GO:0055082","cellular chemical homeostasis", 4.108,-1.327,-6.764, 2.853,-9.7520,0.840,0.364),
c("GO:0007267","cell-cell signaling", 9.025, 5.287, 5.987, 3.195,-5.1175,0.925,0.366),
c("GO:0043408","regulation of MAPK cascade", 3.883, 5.837, 4.526, 2.829,-6.8794,0.689,0.371),
c("GO:0048522","positive regulation of cellular process",27.732,-1.038, 7.337, 3.682,-15.2518,0.798,0.376),
c("GO:0010817","regulation of hormone levels", 2.764,-0.848,-6.705, 2.681,-6.8697,0.892,0.376),
c("GO:0050878","regulation of body fluid levels", 2.862,-1.665,-6.559, 2.696,-4.2541,0.891,0.378),
c("GO:1901654","response to ketone", 1.039, 5.708,-4.850, 2.258,-5.2644,0.898,0.394));

one.data <- data.frame(revigo.data);
names(one.data) <- revigo.names;
one.data <- one.data [(one.data$plot_X != "null" & one.data$plot_Y != "null"), ];
one.data$plot_X <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$plot_X) );
one.data$plot_Y <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$plot_Y) );
one.data$plot_size <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$plot_size) );
one.data$log10_p_value <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$log10_p_value) );
one.data$frequency <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$frequency) );
one.data$uniqueness <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$uniqueness) );
one.data$dispensability <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$dispensability) );

p1 <- ggplot( data = one.data );
p1 <- p1 + geom_point( aes( plot_X, plot_Y, colour = log10_p_value, size = plot_size), alpha = I(0.6) ) + scale_size_area();
p1 <- p1 + scale_colour_gradientn( colours = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red"), limits = c( min(one.data$log10_p_value), 0) );
p1 <- p1 + geom_point( aes(plot_X, plot_Y, size = plot_size), shape = 21, fill = "transparent", colour = I (alpha ("black", 0.6) )) + scale_size_area();
p1 <- p1 + scale_size( range=c(5, 30)) + theme_bw(); # + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = heat_hcl(7), limits = c(-300, 0) );
ex <- one.data [ one.data$dispensability < 0.15, ]; 
p1 <- p1 + geom_text( data = ex, aes(plot_X, plot_Y, label = description), colour = I(alpha("black", 0.85)), size = 3 );
p1 <- p1 + labs (y = "semantic space x", x = "semantic space y");
p1 <- p1 + theme(legend.key = element_blank()) ;
one.x_range = max(one.data$plot_X) - min(one.data$plot_X);
one.y_range = max(one.data$plot_Y) - min(one.data$plot_Y);
p1 <- p1 + xlim(min(one.data$plot_X)-one.x_range/10,max(one.data$plot_X)+one.x_range/10);
p1 <- p1 + ylim(min(one.data$plot_Y)-one.y_range/10,max(one.data$plot_Y)+one.y_range/10);


p1;
```

This code should run standalone so anyone can make the same plot - how can I adjust this code to move the text?

Comment: Did you check ```ggrepel``` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html)?

Comment: Thank you I hadn't heard of this before but it sounds like what I need, will try to make it work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit messy. I found a solution with `ggrepel`, but I do not know if it is the expected figure.

Code:

```
one.data <- data.frame(revigo.data);
names(one.data) <- revigo.names;
one.data <- one.data [(one.data$plot_X != "null" & one.data$plot_Y != "null"), ];
one.data$plot_X <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$plot_X) );
one.data$plot_Y <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$plot_Y) );
one.data$plot_size <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$plot_size) );
one.data$log10_p_value <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$log10_p_value) );
one.data$frequency <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$frequency) );
one.data$uniqueness <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$uniqueness) );
one.data$dispensability <- as.numeric( as.character(one.data$dispensability) );

p1 <- ggplot( data = one.data, aes(plot_X, plot_Y, label = description) );
p1 <- p1 + geom_point( aes( plot_X, plot_Y, colour = log10_p_value, size = plot_size), alpha = I(0.6) ) + scale_size_area();
p1 <- p1 + scale_colour_gradientn( colours = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red"), limits = c( min(one.data$log10_p_value), 0) );
p1 <- p1 + geom_point( aes(plot_X, plot_Y, size = plot_size), shape = 21, fill = "transparent", colour = I (alpha ("black", 0.6) )) + scale_size_area();
p1 <- p1 + scale_size( range=c(5, 30)) + theme_bw(); # + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = heat_hcl(7), limits = c(-300, 0) );
ex <- one.data [ one.data$dispensability < 0.15, ]; 
p1 <- p1 + labs (y = "semantic space x", x = "semantic space y");
p1 <- p1 + theme(legend.key = element_blank()) ;
one.x_range = max(one.data$plot_X) - min(one.data$plot_X);
one.y_range = max(one.data$plot_Y) - min(one.data$plot_Y);
p1 <- p1 + xlim(min(one.data$plot_X)-one.x_range/10,max(one.data$plot_X)+one.x_range/10);
p1 <- p1 + ylim(min(one.data$plot_Y)-one.y_range/10,max(one.data$plot_Y)+one.y_range/10);

library(ggrepel)
p1 <- p1 + geom_label_repel();

p1
```

**Changes:**

Modified: `p1 <- ggplot( data = one.data, aes(plot_X, plot_Y, label = description) );`

Excluded: `p1 <- p1 + geom_text( data = ex, aes(plot_X, plot_Y, label = description), colour = I(alpha("black", 0.85)), size = 3 );`

Added: `p1 <- p1 + geom_label_repel();`

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, it looks good for my main problem. My only issue is that it now brings up the text for some circles which had no text in my original plot, and for my use those circles without text don't need it, is there a way to space out the text without giving every circle in the plot its text?

Comment: Yes, you can add ```\n``` to break lines. For example, ```"movement of cell or subcellular component"``` becomes ```"movement of cell or \nsubcellular component"```